# docker + php-fpm:+ ngnix 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.23.2

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

Hi im trying to lunch multiple project with my docker-compose each image was created by me from scratch FROM debian:11 my react and express runing perfectly but i don't know why ngnix and symfony can't connect to each other if someone know what is the problem i get a 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.23.2 and i don't have any error message when i build with my docker compose in the terminal.

- Dockerfile -
  app/symfony/Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:11

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common gnupg gnupg2 apt-transport-https curl librabbitmq-dev -y && \
    curl -sSL https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt | bash -x && \
    apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install php8.1 \
    php8.1-fpm \
    php8.1-mysql \
    php8.1-pdo \
    php8.1-gd \
    php8.1-cli \
    php8.1-dom \
    php8.1-mbstring \
    php8.1-simplexml \
    php8.1-phar \
    php8.1-dev \
    php8.1-amqp \
    php8.1-redis \
    unzip \
    wget \
    git -y && \
    mkdir /run/php

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \ 
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/symfony/stable/setup.deb.sh' | bash &&\
    apt install symfony-cli

COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock ./

COPY . .

RUN composer install

CMD ["php-fpm8.1", "-F"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

- docker-compose of my project -

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 1999:80
    volumes:
      - ./app/symfony:/var/www/symfony
      - ./conf/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
      - db

  php-fpm:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./app/symfony
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./app/symfony:/var/www/symfony
    depends_on:
      - db
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "php", "-v" ]
      timeout: 30s
      interval: 2s
      retries: 30

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - db

  node_express:
    image: tlugat/debian_express
    build:
      context: ./app/express
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 8081:8081

  react:
    image: tlugat/debian_react
    build:
      context: ./app/react
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
      
  maildev:
    image: maildev/maildev
    ports: 
      - 1080:1080
```

- .default.conf-
  conf/ngnix/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/symfony/public;   
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \\.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution of my problem when you use docker to connect ngnix with php-fpm it's like you have vm in your vm so docker finds it, but don't know what to do when you pass him: fastcgi_pass php-fpm: 9000;
You just need to redirect ngnix to PHP-fpm like this docker understand his need to connect them together